# how to disable client statistic message when using python pulsar client

Tags: python, apache-pulsar

I am using Pulsar python client to subscribe on pulsar.
I'd like to disable client side statistics msg.
However looks like there is no such function in python client.
While, in java we can do something like following:

```
PulsarPublisher.client = PulsarClient.builder().connectionTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                .statsInterval(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

However, in python client I do not see any parameter can control that.
I tried to read online doc from https://pulsar.apache.org/api/python/3.1.x/pulsar.Client.html and I do not find any parameter can do what I want.

Would be great if anybody can help me to figure out.